# CSS animation set value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you please tell me how can I raise the block by clicking on the button, and that it would remain at position -25px?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.block').addClass('animation');
})
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.animation {
  animation: up 750ms;
}

@keyframes up {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<button>UP</button>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. See [ask]. You have word soup now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` property to the `.animation` class rule. That will set the element to the properties of the animation finished state.

Documentation for [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.block').addClass('animation');
})
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.animation {
  animation: up 750ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes up {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<button>UP</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS transforms instead of margins:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.block').addClass('animation');
})
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 750ms;
}

.animation {
  transform: translateY(-25px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<button>UP</button>
```